# How stop-start-restart-status stunnel as a service on centos 7.6

Tags: centos, stunnel

I've installed stunnel 4.5 on centos 7.6.

```
sudo yum -y install stunnel
```

Now i want to stop-start-restart-status stunnel as a service on centos 7.6.
The command below does not work :

```
systemctl start stunnel
```

How can i do that?

---

Take a look at this [link = starting_stopping_restarting_stunnel](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/sect-starting_stopping_restarting_stunnel) :
The command

```
stunnel /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
```

Works.
But the command

```
kill `cat /var/run/stunnel/stunnel.pid`
```

Does not work.It tells :

> cat: /var/run/stunnel/stunnel.pid: No such file or directory

---

**Edit :**
Here is `stunnel.conf` file that i've created in this path (`/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf`).

```
client = no
[squid]
accept  = 1800
connect = 127.0.0.1:8080
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
```

It works fine.

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf` ?

Comment: I found solution here : https://serverfault.com/questions/833702/centos-with-selinux-systemd-and-stunnel and here : https://github.com/liuliang/centos-stunnel-systemd/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution here :
[centos-with-selinux-systemd-and-stunnel](https://serverfault.com/questions/833702/centos-with-selinux-systemd-and-stunnel)
and here :
[centos-stunnel-systemd](https://github.com/liuliang/centos-stunnel-systemd/blob/master/README.md)

---

And here is `stunnel.service` changes for centos 7.6 :

```
[Unit]
Description=SSL tunnel for network daemons
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=stunnel.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/stunnel /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pkill stunnel

# Give up if ping don't get an answer
TimeoutSec=600

Restart=always
PrivateTmp=false
```

Now you can start-enable-stop stunnel as a service :

```
sudo systemctl start stunnel.service
sudo systemctl enable stunnel.service
sudo systemctl stop stunnel.service
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Install stunnel:

`sudo yum install stunnel -y`

#### Configure stunnel:

Create custom stunnel cfg in order to establish connection to some AWS Redis (just for example):

```
sudo touch /etc/stunnel/redis-cli.conf && echo "fips = no
setuid = root
setgid = root
pid = /var/run/stunnel.pid
debug = 7 
delay = yes
options = NO_SSLv2
options = NO_SSLv3
[redis-cli]
   client = yes
   accept = 127.0.0.1:6379
   connect = clustercfg.someredis.example.cache.amazonaws.com:6379" > /etc/stunnel/redis-cli.conf
```

#### Start stunnel:

`sudo stunnel /etc/stunnel/redis-cli.conf`

#### Check that stunnel work:

`sudo netstat -tulnp | grep -i stunnel`

#### Stop stunnel:

There are could be several of stunnel processes:

```
[root@someserver ~]# ps aux | grep stunnel | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
13527
13528
13529
13530
13531
13532
```

The following bash-one-line loop could handle to kill them all:

```
if kill $(ps aux | grep stunnel | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'); then echo "Done"; else echo "No ps left"; fi
```

#### Remove stunnel:

`sudo yum remove stunnel`

#### *Provided instructions work for Amazon Linux 2 as well.

Comment: "sudo stunnel /etc/stunnel/redis-cli.conf" for me it doesnt start it, just print content of file

Comment: Pls check that u have created a proper configuration file on this path `/etc/stunnel/redis-cli.conf`.
There real Redis endpoint and port required. 
It's explained in the "*Configure stunnel*" section above.

Answer (score -1):

Check the `/var/run/stunnel` directory. There might be a `/var/run/stunnel/pid` file (as opposed to `/var/run/stunnel/stunnel.pid`). Or some other similar file. If there is - simply change your command to `` kill `cat /var/run/stunnel/pid` `` or something similar depending on the file name.

Comment: `/var/run/stunnel` > There is no such directory.